Positive quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients

I need a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients $p(x)=-ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a>0$ such that for all $x\in (0,1)$, $p(x)>0$ and the maximum value of $p(x)$ in $(0,1)$ is the least possible value i.e. $\max_{0<x<1} p(x)$ is the least possible value.

We have $p'(x)=-2ax+b$
. So for maxima or minima, $p'(x)=0$ gives  $x=\frac{b}{2a}$. Also since $a>0$, so $p''(x)=-2a<0$. Hence we have $\max_{0<x<1} p(x)=p(\frac{b}{2a})= \frac{b^2}{4a}+c$.
Now we need $a>0$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{b^2}{4a}+c$ is least possible value. We require $p(x)=-ax^2+bx+c>0$. So we require $$-a\left(x-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{b^2+4ac}{4a}>0$$ So we require $$ \frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a}<x< \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a} $$
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

There's no obvious reason why the maximum of $p(x)$ on $(0,1)$ must be the global maximum.   But, then, there's no reason for the maximum to even exist as the interval is open.  What's the maximum of $x^2$ on $(0,1)$?   The supremum is $1$, but it is not realized on the open interval.

@lulu note the coefficient on $x^2$ is negative. This will make the actual maximum exist in this problem.

@OscarLanzi. The global max exists,  but it may be outside that open interval.  If it isn't, then the desired supremum will be at one of the endpoints, and thus not realized.

The required minmax is $1/4$ attained when $a=b=1, c=0$ and the proof is as follows:
Since the maximum occurs at the ends or at $\frac{b}{2a}$ if in the interval and at the ends the result is integral so at least $1$ if the maximum occurs there by the positivity of $p(x)$ in the interval, while for $a=b=1, c=0$ we get the maximum to be $1/4$ (and of course $p(x)>0, x \in (0,1)$ which is guaranteed by $p(0), p(1) \ge 0$ since the minimum of $p$ clearly occurs at one end), we just need to take care of the case: $$0 \le \frac{b}{2a} \le 1, c \ge 0, b+c \ge a$$
But then the maximum is $\frac{b^2}{4a}+c \ge 1$ unless $c=0$ and then we have $b \ge a \ge 1$ so $\frac{b^2}{4a} \ge \frac{1}{4}$ with equality precisely when $a=b=1$ and we are done!

($+1$). Thanks a lot.

happy to be of help
